# How to create a custom file name with a formatted DateTime object?

Tags: c#

I want to save my data to a text file but the file name must contain 2 diferent strings, here's what I've do so far:

```
string input = "Name_"
string input2 = string.Format("stats-{0:yyyy-MM-dd}.txt",
        DateTime.Now);
```

and I can't figure it out how to add here: `string.Format(`**input**`, "stats...`
and the file name must be like:

*Name_stats-2013-11-27.txt*

Comment: I second what @JSQuareD wrote, that is your best option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strings can be concatenated simply by using the + operator:

```
string filename = input + input2;
```

Also, you can add multiple tags to your format-operation:

```
string format = string.Format("{0}stats-{1:yyyy-MM-dd}.txt", input, DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: I still prefer adding tokens instead of concatenating. He will need to do a String.Format() anyways...

Comment: True. But if he ever finds himself in the situation where he needs to concatenate two given strings, this is the easiest way to handle it by a stretch. Both answers have their place here.

Comment: Oh my God!! never think that the answer was so easy!! I am ashamed! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Just do,

```
string input = "Name_"
string input2 = string.Format("stats-{0:yyyy-MM-dd}.txt",
    DateTime.Now);
var fileName = input + input2;
```

or alternatively,

```
var fileName = string.Format(
    "{0}stats-{1:yyyy-MM-dd}.txt",
    "Name_", // Or an actual name
    DateTime.Now)
```

Answer (score 2):

With `Format` you start counting at `0` and then continue to count up each placeholder. So your text would be

```
string result = string.Format("{0}stats-{1:yyyy-MM-dd}.txt", input, DateTime.Now);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not try this? Make your life easier...

```
string input2 = string.Format("{0} stats-{1:yyyy-MM-dd}.txt", input, DateTime.Now);
```